# Ошибка при использовании библиотеки zencad python

Tags: python, pyqt5, zencad

Установил библиотеку zencad в python, хочу немного в ней разобраться, нужно для учебы. Но столкнулся с проблемой, что при запуске кода выпадает ошибка, не смог найти решения в интернете. Вот сам код:

```
from zencad import *

box = box(200, 200, 200, center=True)
sp1 = sphere(120)
sp2 = sphere(60)

model = box - sp1 + sp2

display(model)
show()
```

Вот ошибка:
[image]

Помогите пожалуйста решить